# Calculating $-6^{20} \cdot 5^{70} \pmod {131}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Using Fermat's little theorem:

$(-6^{20} \cdot 5^{70})^{130}\equiv 1 \pmod{131}$

$-6^{2600} \cdot  5^{9100} \equiv 1 \pmod{131}$

I'm a bit stuck on where to go after this since I haven't really dealt with these sort of situations before however I feel like the answer is pretty simple to find from this step. All i'm asking for is a point in the right direction.

Comment: Note that $5^3=125\equiv -6 \pmod{131}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $5^3 \equiv - 6 \pmod{131}$. Then you have

$$-6^{20}\cdot 5^{70} \equiv (5^3)^{20}\cdot 5^{70} \equiv 5^{130} \equiv 1 \pmod{131}$$